# Jquery multiple select (ctrl click) to multiple select (single click)

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I've been looking around online but can't seem to find a straight answer to the question I have.

I have a multi-dropdown like this:

```
<form action="form_action.asp">
<select name="cars" id="mySelect" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now as we all know you can select multiple items in this list by using ctrl+click.

I would like to change this to just a single click.

I've tried a few things:

- Simulating the ctrl while clicking (which was probably the worst idea
  I've had this week).
- Changing the selected attribute. This however    gets the selection
  (the visual part of it atleast) undone when you    click the next
  item.

I'd prefer not to use any plugins, unless there is no other clean way to do so.

Comment: You might use a jquery plugin that makes this for you. Check this out: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: Can you not just keep an `array` variable. So every time you click on an `option` you add that `option` to the `array` and when you click it again you remove it from the `array`. After the click you loop trough the `array` and set the `selected` attribute to all the `options` that you have in the `array`.

Comment: It's an option putvande. Even though it seems more logical to just use a plugin if it's going to be that complex. I'm going to be using this a lot so I really need a solid solution. 

Also the visual part of the work with the array would be a giant *** ;-).

Answer (score -1):

On common form

```
  <select multiple size="5">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Frog">Frog</option> 
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Monkey">Monkey</option> 
    <option value="Parrot">Parrot</option> 
  </select>
```

You can use

```
<script>
window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // toggle selection
        if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) el.removeAttribute('selected');
        else el.setAttribute('selected', '');

        // hack to correct buggy behavior
        var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
    }
}
</script>
```

working example: https://output.jsbin.com/caxacaz

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution to be able to select multiple options without having to click Ctrl

Comment: Not really relevant. Thanks for the time you put in.